# How to open a form, if the form is located in another folder

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

The form and the code that I write to be in different folders
Code:

```
protected string GetClientsHistoryUrl(string iinbin)
{
    return "javascript:window.open('InsurerHistory.aspx?iinbin=" + iinbin.ToString() + "','_blank','status= no, resizable= yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no ')";
}
```

aspx:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLinkIns" runat="server"
  OnClientClick='<%# GetClientsHistoryUrl(Convert.ToString(Eval("iinbin"))) %>'
   Text='<%# Shorten(Eval("InsName"),5,30) %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("InsName") %>'>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Error text: *The resource cannot be found*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the helper function `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute` to obtain the full path to the resource independently of the folder you're in...

Example:

```
protected string GetClientsHistoryUrl(string iinbin)
{
    string javaScript = "javascript:window.open('{0}','_blank','status= no, resizable= yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no')";
    string path = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Path/to/resource/InsurerHistory.aspx?iinbin=" + iinbin);

    return string.Format(javaScript, path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Javascript in Code Behind when there is an easier solution this this.

use code below:

```
Response.Redirect("~/ForExample/yoururl.aspx?iinbin=" + iinbin.ToString());
```

Then Get The Value using `QueryString` in that page.

**Update**

Unfortunately Specification wont work with Response.Redirect, For Specification you may want to go like this:

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('InsurerHistory.aspx?iinbin=" + iinbin.ToString() + "','_blank','status= no, resizable= yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no'</script>");
```

Good luck.

Comment: there was an error: not all code paths return a value

Comment: @Zhandos don't create a method out of it, store the querystring on a private variable, then pass it in that code. if its not an issue do not use LinkButton, instead use a button and write that in codebehind, if didnt work tell me whole scenario so i can give you a better answer

Answer (score 0):

you can give absolute url in window.open() like:

```
return "javascript:window.open('http://www.example.com/InsurerHistory.aspx?iinbin=" + iinbin.ToString() + "','_blank','status= no, resizable= yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no ')";
```

Replace example.com with your domain.

Answer (score 0):

try this `javascript` code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", "window.open('InsurerHistory.aspx?iinbin=" + iinbin.ToString() + "','_blank')", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason: ASP.NET run time unable to locate the resource, so specify the relative path of the resource.

for example consider the folder structure,

- About.aspx
- Account/Login.aspx

Login.aspx page exists inside the account folder, so you need to specify the relative url just like below.

```
   <asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLinkIns" runat="server"
        OnClientClick='javascript:window.open("Account/login.aspx")'
        Text="Login" ToolTip="Login">
    </asp:LinkButton>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
        OnClientClick='javascript:window.open("about.aspx")'
        Text="About" ToolTip="About">
    </asp:LinkButton>
```